# How to move the window default scrollbar above the status bar?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Every program does have the scrollbar above the status bar. Right? Well, not mine.

When i tried to set up my own scroll bars in my program, i suprisingly made them work! So did i manage to get the status bar work too! Hurray! :-) ...But the status bar is ABOVE the scroll bar, when it should be UNDER the scroll bar. How do i move the scrollbar? i couldnt find any functions about moving the scrollbar. unless i create a scrollbar window myself, but that didnt work very well (*it had some weird bug: when i used default height, it became completely invisible scroll bar, and when i used my defined height, the scrollbar had Windows98 theme or something o_O* !)

Here is my status bar creation code:

```
// Create status bar
hStatus = CreateWindowEx(
    0, 
    STATUSCLASSNAME, 
    NULL, 
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SBARS_SIZEGRIP, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 
    hWnd, 
    (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_STATUS, 
    GetModuleHandle(NULL), 
    NULL
);
```

and the window creation:

```
if (!(hWnd=CreateWindowEx(dwExStyle,            // Extended Style For The Window
    "OpenGL",                   // Class Name
    title,                      // Window Title
    dwStyle |                   // Defined Window Style
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | 
    WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WM_HSCROLL | WM_VSCROLL,  // Required Window Style
    0, 0,                       // Window Position
    WindowRect.right-WindowRect.left,       // Calculate Window Width
    WindowRect.bottom-WindowRect.top,       // Calculate Window Height
    NULL,                       // No Parent Window
    NULL,                       // No Menu
    hInstance,                  // Instance
    NULL)))                     // Dont Pass Anything To WM_CREATE
```

There must be some neat trick which i havent realised yet, anyone enlighten me on how to do this properly?

Answer (score 2):

Run notepad and inspect it with spy++ and you'll see the area with the scroll bar and the status bar are two peer windows with a common parent.  You need to do this as well, then use SetWindowPos() to position your two windows relative to each other whenever your parent window changes size or position.